# Haskell: Implementing Num instaces for user-defined newtypes

Tags: haskell, newtype

I have a `Pair` newtype which is just a tuple of `Double`s and I want to be able to use the arithmetic operators with this type. Here's my code, which doesn't compile:

```
module Test where                                   

newtype Pair = Pair (Double, Double)                

instance Num Pair where                             
  Pair (x1, y1) + Pair (x2, y2) = Pair (x1+x2, y1+y2
  Pair (x1, y1) - Pair (x2, y2) = Pair (x1-x2, y1-y2
  Pair (x1, y1) * Pair (x2, y2) = Pair (x1*x2, y1*y2
  abs (Pair (x, y)) = Pair (abs x, abs y)           
  signum (Pair (x, y)) = Pair (signum x, signum y)  
  fromInteger i = Pair (fromInteger i, fromInteger i)

func :: Pair -> Double -> Pair                      
func p d = p * d
```

Here's the erro GHC throws:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Test             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:14:16:
Couldn't match expected type `Pair' with actual type `Double'
In the second argument of `(*)', namely `d'
In the expression: p * d
In an equation for `func': func p d = p * d
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I had thought that defining `from Integer` and `*` would have been enough here, can someone advise what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE

If I add the following instance:

```
instance Fractional Pair where                          
  Pair (x1, y1) / Pair (x2, y2) = Pair (x1/x2, y1/y2)   
  fromRational r = Pair (fromRational r, fromRational r)
```

then my function still doesn't compile, but in ghci, I can do

```
> Pair (1.0, 2.0) * 3.4
Pair (3.4,6.8)
```

but not:

```
> Pair (1.0, 2.0) * 3.4 :: Double

<interactive>:206:1:
Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Pair'
In the return type of a call of `Pair'
In the first argument of `(*)', namely `Pair (1.0, 2.0)'
In the expression: Pair (1.0, 2.0) * 3.4 :: Double
```

I'm still struggling to understand why this is happening.

Comment: `(*)` is `Num a => a -> a -> a` not `(Num a, Num b) => a -> b ->` ... something?

Comment: But I thought the fromInteger function would "cast" the Double argument into a Pair, which would then be multiplied with the first Pair. Is that not how it works? If not, how can I implement something like it?

Comment: @mszep `fromInteger` takes an `Integer`, not a `Double`.

Comment: @AJFarmar I see, thanks. Please have a look at my update: when I add the  Fractional typeclass, I can almost do what I want, but not quite, and my function still doesn't compile.

Comment: Please don't define instances like that. `Num` is for _numbers_, not for “anything that can be added”. At least the `Fractional` one really isn't sound, seeing as `a/b` isn't safe for `b = Pair (1,0)`, even though `abs b ≠ 0`. — I think you want the [`VectorSpace` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.10.2/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html) (which has tuple instances out of the box).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use implicit `fromInteger` on an argument, which makes zero sense.

Firstly, `fromInteger` (or `fromRational`) is only implicit on **Literals**. Ie:

```
6 = fromInteger 6
4.1 = fromRational 4.1
```

But this is **not true**:

```
a = fromInteger a  -- Not true!
```

Your argument `d` is not a literal, so you will have to manually use `realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b`:

```
func :: Pair -> Double -> Pair
func p d = p * realToFrac d
```

Answer (score 3):

```
func :: Pair -> Double -> Pair
func p d = p * d
```

You're trying to multiply a `Pair` by a `Double`, but both arguments to `*` must have the same type.

Comment: See my reply to Bartek above; Shouldn't the fromInteger function take care of that?